# How to slipstream Ubuntu the easy way?

Tags: remastersys, uck, customizer, ubuntu-builder

There are a few dead projects that could do this:

- [ubuntu-builder](https://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/)
- [Remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com/)

Too Compilcated

- [Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~customizer-dev-team)
- [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/)

---

The question before I go to bed:

> How to slipstream Ubuntu the easy way?

Meaning a `GUI`

**Tweaks/Features**

- Autostart in LiveCD mode
- Full support of Windows filesystems
- If possible support of Mac OS X hfs+ filesystems(Not needed, but nice to have)
- Recovery/backup tools slipstreamed.
- Gparted, with support of all filesystems related to Windows, as that is what needs the most fixing
- Extremely lite!
- Wine, for Anti Malware tools.

This will be used in a TestCD, which i will use, if i want to backup Windows machines. And if also possible wine, to scan the Windows drives for virusses with mbam superantispyware. Already tested them. They work fine.

Comment: After learning to build custom live CD, IMO the best and easiest method is the debian live scripts. There is an unavoidable learning curve if you wish to build live CD and again IMO the debian live scripts are easiest to learn and modify. Graphical tools come and go and fail, IMO, because there is no replacement to learning the mechanics.